# Is there a way to keep a cURL command from interpreting a semicolon in macOS Catalina?

Tags: shell, macos-catalina

Running a cURL command to upload the contents of a file (by filling a form) like the following `curl -L -X POST -F 'edit=filename' http://website.local/example -F 'filecontent=test;2;3'` will work on High Sierra but won't on Catalina

Catalina keeps stopping at the semicolon `;` and ignores the rest because it's interpreting the semicolon and outputs:

`Warning: skip unknown form field: 2
Warning: skip unknown form field: 3`

I've tried different things like escaping it `\;` and single-quoting it but still no success, also tried changing to bash or different shells besides zsh.

Following the example `curl -F  'colors="red;  green;  blue";type=text/x-myapp'  example.com` works, I'm just trying to read the contents from a file now. The code that works on High Sierra is `-F "filecontent=$(<Example.txt)"`

The file I'm uploading contains semicolons and it uploads the text up until the first semicolon

curl 7.54.0 in High Sierra

curl 7.64.1 in Catalina

Comment: Which shell is this? Zsh?

Comment: adding console log will also help.

Comment: Huh? Semicolons don't have any meaning to the shell in single quotes in *any* version of bash, or in zsh either. I'd much more easily believe that this is a new version of curl, and that the shell has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @LexLopez, ...keep in mind that by the time `curl` gets started, it's not handed a command line (with quotes/shell syntax/etc intact), but just an array of C strings. Semicolons inside those strings are *literal data* as far as the shell is concerned; whether they have any other meaning to `curl` is something that `curl`'s manual should be consulted for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy curl version is indeed different

Comment: BTW, one thing you can do to see what the literal argument list is after the shell is done with it would be `printf '<%s>\n' curl -L -X POST -F 'edit=filename' http://website.local/example -F 'filecontent=test;2;3'` to print your argument list one-per-line, each item preceded by `<` and terminated by `>`, with all the quoting removed, exactly as they're actually passed (well, "exactly" as long as none of the arguments contain a literal newline, cursor/terminal control characters, or the like).

Comment: the file I'm uploading contains new lines and semicolons which go into the 'filecontent=$(<Example.txt)' argument and the cURL command uploads everything up until the first semicolon in the file

Comment: Then you **definitely** want `--form-string`, if your semicolons are supposed to be literal data. Or use `-F 'filecontent=<Example.txt'`, if you want curl itself to do the job of opening and reading `Example.txt`.

Comment: ...anyhow, with `-F "filecontent=$(<file)"`, you have bash, not curl, responsible for reading the file, so `--form-string` turning off curl's file-reading functionality is a nonissue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change from `--form` to `--form-string` to prevent `;key=value` (as used for `;type=text/x-myapp` assignments) from being parsed.

---

Thus, you can change the pertinent line from:

```
curl "${other_args[@]}" -F "filecontent=$(<file)"
```

to:

```
curl "${other_args[@]}" --form-string "filecontent=$(<file)"
```

Comment: how would you add the contents of the file with --form-string?

Comment: If you're already using `"filecontent=$(<filename)"`, there's no reason that would stop working -- that's something *bash* is responsible for doing, before curl is invoked at all. (It's `'filecontent=<filename'` with no `$(<...)` construct that `--form-string` disables).

Comment: It worked. The code is `--form-string "filecontent=$(<Example.txt)"`. Thanks so much

Comment: If you don't think the answer makes that clear enough, feel free to propose an edit making its application more clear; since it's flagged "Community Wiki", that means I'm not personally taking credit / rep points for it, and anyone's welcome to edit it without asking approval.

Comment: Where should the final line go so the answer is complete including reading from a file? question, answer or comment?